# Error deploying SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm trying to deploy a new empty SQL DW on a Brazil South Server and keep getting the same error:

```
    {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "A operação de recurso foi concluída com o estado de provisionamento de terminal 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "40827",
        "message": "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Did anyone already got the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to hear you're having an issue provisioning a database with the SQL DW service. Can you follow the steps in this link to create a ticket and we'll investigate immediately?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/

Comment: I had issues with my subscription and couldn't open new tickets but that's over now. It appears that SQL DW is unavailable in Brazil South.